# Camera permission is not working

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, android-manifest, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV4Android version 3.0.0. I am trying to access the camera through OpenCV lib, actually I managed to open it.But the problem i am currently facing is, when i create a new project and importe OpenCV lib I can not use the camera and I receive the following message when i run the App
despite the permissions are added to the manifest file as shown below

please let me know what i am missing to run the Camera??

**Note**
i have several project with OpenCV imported and the camera with these projects works fine...the issue i am facing happened today when i create a new project

**error message**

[image]

**manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**OpenCVLibrary300**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.edgedetectionlaplace_03"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':openCVLibrary300')
}
```

Comment: close all camera apps, restart your device and try again

Comment: @QadirHussain i tried it but it didnt solve the issue

Comment: Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enabling the Camera permission ? did you already try this?

Comment: @AlainProfessional where can i find that??

Answer (score 2):

You already put this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Now try this :

```
Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enabling the Camera permission ?
```

then like Qadir Hussain said

```
kill any other apps that are using the camera.
```

if nothing works, check if you devise is compatible with your lib.

Comment: would you please tell me where can i find "Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enabling the Camera permission "

Comment: Check this article: [Control your app permissions on Android 6.0 and up](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en).